# What are the weaknesses of the QPluginLoader approach?

Tags: qt, plugins

Here the official *Qt Creator* code repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator.git
```

Qt Creator uses `QPluginLoader`.

What are the weaknesses of the `QPluginLoader` approach? What are the differences from `QLibrary`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**QtPluginloader** cannot be used if your application is statically linked against Qt.

In this case, you will also have to link to plugins statically. You can use **QLibrary** if you need to load dynamic libraries in a statically linked application.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpluginloader.html

Hope it helps.
Best Regards